# Multiple MYSQL join using year portion of date field

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

`events (id, event_date, type)`

`champions (id, year, player_id, type)`

`players (id, fname, lname)`

I want to create a chart with 2 columns.  One that lists each year (without duplicates) that exists in either the `events` table or the `champions` table. The other that lists the name of the champion for the given year (if one exists).  I only want to include rows where the event type is `night`.

So the output might look like this:

```
|Year|Champion|

|2015|  (empty)      |   <---- no champion defined for 2015 yet, so column is empty

|2014|  David Smith|  <--- no events in the database for 2014, but a champion is defined, so he shows up in column

|2012|  Jimmy Garland|
```

(No events or champions in 2013 so the row is skipped.)

I tried this query, but it ends up giving me 2 rows for 2014.  One has an empty second column and the other has a champion in the second column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM events.event_date) AS evyear, champions.*, players.*
FROM events 
LEFT JOIN champions ON EXTRACT(YEAR FROM events.event_date)=champions.year
    LEFT OUTER JOIN players ON champions.player_id=players.id AND champions.type = 'night'
WHERE events.type = 'night'
ORDER BY evyear DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You look to be on the right track, but you need to get all your event years from a subquery.

```
select q.`year`, coalesce(concat(p.fname, ' ', p.lname), 'No Champion') champion from (
  select distinct year(event_date) `year`
    from events
  ) q
  left join champions c
    on q.`year` = c.`year` and c.type = 'night'
  left join players p
    on c.player_id = p.id
```

[small demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cad9f/8)